# extract an object from image using some image processing filter

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on an application which something like that I have an image and e.g. there is a glass or a cup or a chair in it. The object can be of any type
My question here is that is there any way that i can apply some image processing filters or something like that which returns me an image that just contain the object and the background is transparent

Comment: OpenCV has background subtraction techniques you can use for this.

Comment: Actually the background is not static, it can be any thing and also the object could be anything, and i want the object extracted with its background transparent

Answer (score 0):

You can use object detection methods such as 
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/object_detection.html
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html

to detect the object, plot a bounding box around it and extract it from the image.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have read the object detection but its using a template to detect the object but I don't have any template, and the background is also not static mean there isn't a single background

Answer (score 0):

depends on your application, but you can also use image difference (background subtraction) to get the object...

Comment: Dear Alex, I am assuming you don't have computer vision background. Background subtraction is a legitimate image processing filter. It predates object detection also. Background difference is also very straightforward to implement, just subtract the two images and threshold them. This obviously can lead to the answer that the question was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

- Actually I have solved the problem
- the issue was I do not want to use any advance method that uses template matching or neural networks or anything like that
- so in my case the aim was to recognize an object in an image and that object could be anything (e.g. a table,a cellphone, a person, a shirt etc) and the catch was that there could be at most one object in an image
- so just using watershed segmentation of opencv I was able to separate the object from the background
- but the threshold used for the watershed differs with respect to the frequency of the image and the difference of shades of the object from the background